# Python JSON encryption got error and psycopg2 converts JSON data to single-quote

Tags: python, json, psycopg2, public-key-encryption

I am  trying to encrypt JSON data that is stored in a database. I have a public key which is used for the encryption and is also stored in a table in database . This is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import . . . .
.
.
#get json data from database
def getJson():
    sql = '''
    SELECT  json_data from table1;
    '''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    return result

# get public key to encrypt
def getPubKey():
    sql = '''
    select public_key from table2 
    where col1 = 'xxx'
    and col2 = 'yyy'
    limit 20;
    '''
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rsa_pub = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return rsa_pub

def encrypt_rsa(_rsa_pub, plaintext):
    key_txt = _rsa_pub.encode()
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(key_txt, default_backend())

    # encrypt plaintext
    pad = padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                   algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                   label=None)
    return public_key.encrypt(plaintext, pad)


def run():
    message = getJson()
    pk = getPubKey()
    for x in message:
        json.dumps(x)
        enc = encrypt_rsa(pk , x)
        enc = base64.b64encode(enc).decode()
        print(enc)
```

I adapted encrypt_rsa() function from [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#kms-howto-encrypt-python). And I got this error:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'unsigned char *' must be a cdata pointer, not dict
```

So I tried printing the json data that I queried, which turned out to be single-quoted like this: `{'data':'abc'}`, which is weird because JSON format should use double quotes. So I tried query in pSQL and got double-quoted data `{"data":"abc"}`. I am not sure that is the reason for the error or not.

My question here is

1. It seems like `psycopg2` converts my JSON result to single-quoted text instead of the default double quote. So, how can I force a double quote like normal?
2. If it becomes double-quoted and the error still occurs, how can I encrypt a JSON database with what I have tried on my code?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypt.py", line 78, in <module>
   run()
  File "encrypt.py", line 70, in run
   enc = encrypt_rsa(pk , x)
 File "encrypt.py", line 56, in encrypt_rsa
   return public_key.encrypt(plaintext, pad)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 446, in encrypt
   return _enc_dec_rsa(self._backend, self, plaintext, padding)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 68, in _enc_dec_rsa
   return _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx(backend, key, data, padding_enum, padding)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 123, in _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx
   res = crypt(pkey_ctx, buf, outlen, data, len(data))
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'unsigned char *' must be a cdata pointer, not dict
```

Comment: I'm confused. It doesn't look like you're executing the SQL at all. You just create a string with it, then run `cursor.execute()` without arguments. Also, can you provide the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to write it when I create a question. the actual code have that

Comment: updated @glibdud

Comment: I can't be sure, this may just be another transcription error, but it could be as simple as changing `json.dumps(x)` to `x = json.dumps(x)`.

Comment: Got this error instead `TypeError: initializer for ctype 'unsigned char *' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str`

Comment: Oh so I add `key_txt = _rsa_pub.encode('ascii')` and `x = json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8')` and no error occurd. But still want to fix the psycopg2 problem. I really need that double quote :((

Comment: It was showing you single-quotes because you weren't actually json encoding the object; python was just showing you a dict. Now that you fixed that, I think you'll find the double-quotes are there.

Comment: Yeah so I print out x after json.dumps() and got exact result `b'{"":""}`